# White objects on white thumbnails are invisible, so can I change the thumbnail background?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I cannot find any option to change the default white background of the layers panel thumbnails in Illustrator CS6, thus all white objects are invisible and I cannot quickly work on them. 
 I've found related questions via Google, but from 2009 and without solution, so probably, someone at present time knows how to deal with this issue?

[image]

Comment: in this tutorial the layers are on transparent - so apparently it is doable the question is how?
http://www.lynda.com/Illustrator-tutorials/Transparency-grid-paper-color/61020/67516-4.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of one well known Ai programmer I've found some interesting solution:

View->Show Transparency Grid and set the colors of the grid to black-

This will give some nice black background to the thumbnails -

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's been reported to Adobe for years.

It has been requested to at least add a light/dark toggle or something.

But, in the end.....

**There's *nothing* the end user can do to alter the thumbnail background color.**

Comment: Queue dramatic chipmunk video. You could just label the layers appropriately though.

Comment: @Scott what do you say about a solution below? Any drawbacks?

Comment: @Ilan seems okay, but that only works when the transparency grid is showing. A black background while working on objects is not always wanted and can be distracting. FOr CS6 it only works on the Object level from what I can tell. It's a decent workaround, but not ideal.

Comment: @Scott yes, this is the level I wanted it to work. It is not a perfect solution, probably gimmick one, but it is better then nothing at all $)

Comment: So you would say it worked reasonably? I am interested in knowing if it worked.

Comment: It works, but even when creating white objects, I don't work on a black background. That is what's needed for this workaround to function. But... you can simply toggle the Transparency grid on and off. On a scale of 1 to 10 in terms of usability, I'd give it a 6. Better than average, but not ideal.